# Get Duration of a Video from S3 File

Tags: java, amazon-s3, fine-uploader

I have a Java app (hosted with Elastic Beanstalk) that uses "Fine Uploader" to upload video files directly to Amazon S3.

I'm having issues getting the duration of that uploaded video (preferably duration in seconds)

The only metadata I can get access to tells me the "content-length", which is the size in bytes... but I don't believe that's something that can be used to accurately tell me the duration of the video.

I've seen some people suggest putting the details of the length of the video in a tag before uploading to S3, which is fine, but I don't know how to get the length of a video with the "Fine Uploader".

Any ideas?

Comment: Fine Uploader doesn't do anything with videos other than upload them. And attempting to read videos browser side is likely going to be quite challenging. Your best bet is to use a server-side approach. Pull the video from S3 and analyze it using an appropriate library or tool, such as ffmpeg.

Comment: Is there any way to avoid pulling the entire video?

Comment: Should be possible: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=117551

Comment: @RayNicholus, the article you posted refers to a PHP solution using an unrelated AWS service (elastic transcoding). I'm not using transcoding, I'm just uploading a file to S3 and hoping to get the duration of the video.

Comment: Read the whole thread

Comment: These solutions assume you can install FFMpeg on your server, which is then used by Java libraries. I'm running my app in AWS (Elastic Beanstalk) and don't have access to installing ffmpeg

Comment: Why not? Beanstalk is just an easy way to setup an ELB to manage EC2 instances and then update the underlying instances when you need to deploy a new version of your app. You should have full access to the EC2 instances. You can shell to these boxes and do whatever you need.

Comment: AH okay, that's a good point... I'm not familiar with Linux at all unfortunately, but I suppose I could find a way to install FFMpeg

Comment: `apt-get install ffmpeg`